# What is "unitOfWork" thing in symfony2 and doctrine2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I was reading Doctrine2 documentation and it mention at various places about `unitOfWork`
What is that. Can someone please explain me. that why i need that and what is its use for

Comment: [`The UnitOfWork is responsible for tracking changes to objects during an "object-level" transaction and for writing out changes to the database in the correct order.`](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unit of work in simple terms is a graph that begins constructing whenever related nodes (in the case of Symfony2, the entities) are changed.

[image]

When you execute the unit of work, it will track the changes of the affected entities (marked as dirty) of records and apply the changes to all of them in a single blow (transaction)

For more information: [P of EAA Catalog: Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html)